# Installing DDR3L 1600MHz on HP 8200 Elite (DDR3 1333MHz)

Tags: memory, ddr3

I tried to read as much as I can but I want to be sure:

I want to install: Kingston 8GB 1600MHz DDR3L Non-ECC CL11 DIMM 1.35V

On my: [HP Compaq 8200 Elite](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04168353.pdf))

Which supports: DDR3 1333MHz

Am I safe? 
Thanks :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/577414/what-drawbacks-are-there-when-using-memory-that-is-faster-than-what-is-rated-by

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/753502/what-happens-if-i-use-ram-of-a-faster-speed-than-the-cpu-supports

Comment: Thanks Ali, I understood that it's safe, still waiting for safety answer about DDR3(L) :)

Comment: @Hashem - If you understood that it is safe, then don't ask "Am I safe?", at least not without clarifying your statement.

Comment: I'm sorry @Rambound, what I meant was that the two links above are talking about installing faster RAM than what is rated by the MB, but not about installing a DDR3L on DDR3 slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work, but I would **not try that**. The important part is the L in DDR3L of the modules you want to use. This is low-voltage RAM which uses 1.35V, while your PC provides 1.5V. Also DDR3L RAM is (usually) more expensive than DDR3 RAM, so just use normal DDR3 modules.

Apart from that, the frequency is not a problem. So, if your PC supports only 1333MHz you can use 1600MHz modules (which will run at 1333Hz). So you might spend to much money on modules which are faster than what your PC can utilize, but sometimes faster modules are cheaper.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, the L is cheaper than the normal :D ,
I read that the DDR3L can run on both 1.5V and 1.35V, do you agree?

Comment: As per http://www.jedec.org/news/pressreleases/jedec-publishes-widely-anticipated-ddr3l-low-voltage-memory-standard, "Under the new standard, DDR3L memory devices will be functionally compatible to DDR3 memory devices, but not all devices will be interoperable at both voltage ranges."

Comment: They might work with 1.5V, but if the specification does not say that they can they might also just break as soon as you press the power button. So it boils down to gambling.

Answer (score 0):

The service manual for the HP 8200 Elite ***explicitly warns*** that the system does **not** support low-voltage DDR3 modules. Attempting to use them may fry your system. As a side note, this particular workstation model seems to be quite picky in what kind of DIMMS it will support, so *Read The Foreboding Manual* and choose your parts carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed a bunch of DDR3L RAM ("DDR3L / DDR3 1600MHz (DDR3L-1600) PC3L-12800 / PC3-12800 Non-ECC Unbuffered 1.35V/1.5V CL11 2Rx8 Dual Rank 240 Pin UDIMM") in several of this exact model of computer (HP Compaq 8200 Elite) and it worked fine.

The warning in the service manual is about DDR3U, not DDR3L.

I decided to give it a try, despite the dire warning in another comment, based on research (e.g. [this page](https://digitaladvisor.com/ram/ddr3-vs-ddr3l/)) which says that DDR3L is backwards-compatible with DDR3 because DDR3L can also run at the higher voltage – and [Crucial's memory upgrade page for that computer](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/hp---compaq/hp-compaq-8200-elite-convertible-minitower) lists several DDR3L RAM options.